# How can I change keyboard style to Numeric in Winrt?

Tags: keyboard, windows-runtime, windows-phone, inputscope

I was using InputScope in Windows Phone for open numeric Keyboard and I need its equaivalent in WinRT, Windows8.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InputScope is still available in WinRT-XAML on the TextBox control, in the same way it is on Windows Phone development.

Add a TextBox to a page and you'll find the property under Common grouping.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow in my company and reply it's state. Tahnk you for your answer.